# Not able to retrieve Session attributes in JSP

Tags: jsp, session, jsf-1.2

I have JSF 1.2 based `Servlet`. Am setting `Session` attributes in bean of my `Servlet`. Bean is in Request scope. In this `Servlet` there is a link. When this link is clicked it calls another `Servlet`. This 2nd Servlet is not JSF based. It just contains one JSP page to display data. Am trying to display data in this JSP by retrieving `Session` attributes set in the 1st `Servlet`. But, the data that am getting in JSP page is `null`. Session ID is same in both the Servlets. I have below relevant code in my JSP page.

```
<%@page language="java" session="true" %>
<%@page session="true" %>
 session = request.getSession();
 String userName = (String)session.getAttribute("uname");
```

Below is the way am setting Session attributes in bean

```
HttpSession session = null;
    HttpServletRequest req = null;
    req = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
    session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("uname", this.uname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) to retrieve your session attributes. For e.g.:

```
${sessionScope['uname']}
```

Comment: I tried <c:out value='<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("uname")%>'/> and <c:out value="${sessionScope.uname}"/> and <c:out value="${sessionScope['uname']}"/> . None of them worked!

Comment: One more thing. Session attribute is set in the bean when some action is called. After this a User has many pages to navigate. Finally he will end up in 2nd Servlet where in the Session attribute being set in 1st Servlet's bean is being tried to display in a JSP page